# Breakpoints stopped working - WPF app was Desktop-Bridged from Visual Studio

Tags: wpf, uwp, windows-10, desktop-bridge

Last month I [Desktop-Bridged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-root) my one simple `WPF` app using in latest version of `VS2017 - ver 15.9` on `Windows10 - Update 1809`. The WPF app was also developed on the exact same environment. Last month, the `breakpoints` in debug mode were working.

But today the breakpoints are not working. According to this [official link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-debug#debug-your-app):

```
If you created your package by using the new packaging project available in the 15.4 release of Visual Studio 2017, Just set the packaging project as the startup project, and then press F5 to debug your app.
```

**Please note**:

1. This month, I upgraded `VS2017` to `VS2019 - Ver16.1.3`. But that probably should not make any difference since my other old projects work fine in `VS2019`.
2. As shown below, I've verified that the Packaging Project in the solution is indeed the Startup project (as instructed in the link above).
3. The WPF app is a sample app using the code from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-save-load-and-print-richtextbox-content) with user interface shown in image 2 below.

**Snapshot of `VS2019` solution**:

[image]

**UI of the app**:

[image]

**Snapshot of `VS2019` top toolbar**:

[image]

Comment: Please open your visual studio and **'Click Help -> Send Feedback -> Report a problem'** on top menus.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something during the update messed up your machine settings. Can you check [Developer Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development) is still active? The configurations you've done on your SLN are good, so breakpoints should be working as expected.